# How to change column level in df.pivot()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like that the column introduced as argument in `df.pivot()` act as outter level, not inner.

This is how my **dataframe** looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'Zone':'Zone 00', 'Area':1,'A':2, 'B':51,'C':5,'D':1}
d2 = {'Zone':'Zone 00', 'Area':2,'A':6, 'B':5,'C':36,'D':2}
d3 = {'Zone':'Zone 01', 'Area':1,'A':2, 'B':8,'C':9,'D':22}
d4 = {'Zone':'Zone 01', 'Area':2,'A':8, 'B':55,'C':19,'D':42}
d5 = {'Zone':'Zone 02', 'Area':1,'A':14, 'B':42,'C':8,'D':23}
d6 = {'Zone':'Zone 02', 'Area':2,'A':23, 'B':96,'C':75,'D':12}

dics = (d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)
df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in dics])
```

[image]

I **pivot** the dataframe to display the params (A, B, C, D) by zone's areas and not by the own params.

```
df.pivot(columns='Area', index='Zone',values=['A','B','C','D'])
```

But I obtain the column's level ordered in the inverse way:

[image]

This is what I'd like to obtain:
[image]

I have tried `df.swaplevel(axis=1)` method, but no inverse grouper is set. It only changes level order.

Does anybody knows how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `swaplevel`:

```
(df.pivot(columns='Area', index='Zone',values=['A','B','C','D'])
   .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
Area      1              2            
          A   B  C   D   A   B   C   D
Zone                                  
Zone 00   2  51  5   1   6   5  36   2
Zone 01   2   8  9  22   8  55  19  42
Zone 02  14  42  8  23  23  96  75  12
```